# DIV(overflow-y: scroll) within DIV(position:fixed) overflowing parent's bounds

Tags: css, css-position, overflow

I'm setting up an online store.

When the user clicks a product, a popup div holds basic item information, and some reviews. This popup has no fixed height, and is instead set with `position: fixed` and top/bottom/right/left bounds

I've appended a mockup to the bottom of this post. The coloring and transparency is just to help illustrate.

No matter what I've tried, short of setting the height of the `div.scrollable`, it always overflows its parent. Can CSS alone fix this, and how? Or must I use javascript to calculate the height. **I would like the `.scrollable` element to fill the remaining height of `.page`, but not exceed the bounds/overflow**.

I've experimented with flexbox, but have seen no difference in result so didn't include any of that here.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#content {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  padding: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#novella {
  position:fixed;
  top: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.productInfo {background-color: white;}

.scrollable {
  background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.5);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.grid {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 25%);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: flex-start;
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ul class="grid">
    <li>Fubar Product</li>
    <li>Foo Product</li>
    <li>Bar Product</li>
    <li>Fu Product</li>
    <li>CSS Knowledge</li>
    <li>Fubar Product</li>
    <li>Foo Product</li>
    <li>Bar Product</li>
    <li>Fu Product</li>
    <li>CSS Knowledge</li>
    <li>Fubar Product</li>
    <li>Foo Product</li>
    <li>Bar Product</li>
    <li>Fu Product</li>
    <li>CSS Knowledge</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="novella">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="productInfo">
        Fubar product.<br>
        $99.99<br>
        It's the greatest, beyond all others
      </div>
      <div class="scrollable">
        <ul>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood what you want. Tell me if it is something like [this](https://imgur.com/DwaiQ3f).

Comment: @ArthurPereira Yep, to stop the overflow, to contain the reviews within the scrollable DIV.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the .scrollable div to be scrollable you have to set a max-height for it.

Also if you let the bottom style on your #novella it will make it strech, causing the div to go from top to bottom.

So you have to remove #novella bottom position style and set a max-height on .scrollable..

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#content {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  padding: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#novella {
  position:fixed;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.productInfo {background-color: white;}

.scrollable {
  background-color: rgba(225,225,225,.5);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height:150px;
}

.grid {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 25%);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: flex-start;
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <ul class="grid">
    <li>Fubar Product</li>
    <li>Foo Product</li>
    <li>Bar Product</li>
    <li>Fu Product</li>
    <li>CSS Knowledge</li>
    <li>Fubar Product</li>
    <li>Foo Product</li>
    <li>Bar Product</li>
    <li>Fu Product</li>
    <li>CSS Knowledge</li>
    <li>Fubar Product</li>
    <li>Foo Product</li>
    <li>Bar Product</li>
    <li>Fu Product</li>
    <li>CSS Knowledge</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="novella">
    <div class="page">
      <div class="productInfo">
        Fubar product.<br>
        $99.99<br>
        It's the greatest, beyond all others
      </div>
      <div class="scrollable">
        <ul>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
          <li>It was great</li>
          <li>I liked it</li>
          <li>Not what I wanted</li>
          <li>Sized perfectly</li>
          <li>Not great</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ps: If you want to set height with responsive css you will have to give an height for you parent #novella.

Answer (score 0):

I derived a solution from [this answer by greenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64374418/3917091). I'd prefer something that was more obvious, but this does exactly what I wanted.

In a parent element with two children, apply this to the parent, in my case my `.page` element.

```
grid-template-rows: minmax(60px, auto) minmax(0, 100%);
// where 60px is the minimum height of your first element,
// and 0 is the minimum height of your selecond)
```

Now, because I'm not specifying height of any of the parent elements, it cascaded to all the way up to my `.novella` element, which implies a height based on `top` and `bottom` bounds. It's unfortunate that no other CSS method I tried would accept this implied height.